# Android Studio Gradle Project Sync Failed - I want to build a streaming app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

So I'm new to App Development, and I'm struggling with the Gradle Sync:

> Blockquote Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'MyApplication' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project 'MyApplication' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

That is the error message I get.

This is the code I am using

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


    apply plugin: 'project-report'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Please help with a way to fix this,

thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two `build.gradle` files in your Android Studio project. The one that you edited is in the project's root directory. That's not the file you should have put those lines in. The other `build.gradle` is in your module's directory (e.g., `app/`). Those four `compile` lines go in a `dependencies` closure in *that* `build.gradle` file.

This is even mentioned in the comment in the file:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/HTTP/Picasso) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android)) uses some of those same dependencies. My top-level `build.gradle` file does not have the `compile` statements:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Instead, they are in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```